# Pack gradle multi-module build into one package

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, android-library

I have an Android Libaray project which consists of 3 sub-modules and looks like

```
root
  \___javaModule1
  \___javaModule2
  \___androidLibModule
```

- `javaModule2` depends on `javaModule1`
- `androidLibModule` depends on `javaModule1` and `javaModule2`

All works fine, but resulted `*.aar` file contains only classes from `androidLibModule`. Actually my config creates 2 separate jars and 1 aar. But I'm want to pack them all into one aar file.

Is it possible with current versions of build tools and 3-modules project structure? Or I'm should move my classes from `javaModule1` and `javaModule2` into `androidLibModule` and creates one-module-based project?

Comment: do you find the solution? I also met this problem.